# How can I solve a binary quadratic program in MATLAB?

Tags: optimization, matlab, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I'm not an expert in MATLAB. Can I use MATLAB function `fminimax` to solve the problem below?

---

Let's say I have matrix $\mathbf P$ and let's say $\bf Px = b$. My problem consists of

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| {\bf P} {\bf x} \|_2^2& \\ \text{subject to} & {\bf P} {\bf x} \geq {\bf y} \\ & \ell \leq {\bf 1}^\top {\bf x} \leq u \\ & x_i \in \{0,1\}\end{array}$$

where $\mathbf P$, $\mathbf y$, $\ell$, and $u$ are given. The purpose of $\mathbf x$ is to get specific parts of $\mathbf P$ into $\mathbf b$.

Comment: Does $P$ always have exactly one row? Ifnot, the objective function, $b$ is not a scalar, so it is not clear exactly what you want the objective to be. Do you actually want this to be min (with respect to $X$) max(b), where the max is over the elements of a vector?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone P is a matrix with more than one row. And yes, b is a vector; so min b means min norm of b. Should have probably clarified that. x is the input, b is the one I want to find out.

Comment: Which norm are you using?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. 2-norm

Comment: Is it ok to relax the constraint $x_i \in \{0, 1\}$ to $0\leq x_i \leq 1$. Also, is $P$ invertible?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. No, the whole purpose of this problem is whether we take an element from P or not. And yes, P is invertible.

Comment: If $P$ is invertible, then why don't you eliminate $b$? Also, relaxations can yield pretty good results, especially if you use the 1-norm which typically results into a sparse minimizer that is close to the true solution.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. So sorry, P is NOT invertible. My mind went blank there for a second. I was using 2-norm, but ok let's assume we can relax the conditions and use 1-norm.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 2-norm

Comment: Relaxing the problem allows you to use `fminimax`, provided that the feasible set is nonempty. You can use this generic solver, but in case you use the 2-norm, then you can use `quadprog` instead. For 1-norm, the problem is an LP which is solvable with `linprog`.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the edit. P is 2x4, x is 4x1, b and y are 2x1, l and u are scalars.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks, will try those.

Comment: @novice5095 That information should be included in the question itself.

Comment: You're welcome. I think next time it's better to ask this type of question in a MATLAB forum, rather than here. Or, at least try to formulate your problem and question better, so that you can get useful answers and solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You need a mixed-integer quadratic programming solver for this, such as Mosek or Gurobi, available also for MATLAB, free for academia

With a modelling Toolbox such as YALMIP (developed by me) with some installed MIQP solver, you would conveniently solve it then as

```
x = binvar(n,1);
optimize([l<=sum(x)<=u,P*x >= 0],x'*P'*P*x);
```

However, with the trivial size you speak about, nothing will beat brute-force enumeration.